JNDI Lookup failed: Channel is closed by peer
I'm migrating a microservice from springboot 2.x.x to 3.x.x, My project is working fine before migrating to springboot 3.x.x. I'm using .jks file for certification and Solace JMS.  I've changed Topic, Queue Message etc from javax to jakarta. but Context, InitialContext and NamingException is not present in the jakarta library.
I've tried below steps:

Used same Context, InitialContext and NamingException coming from javax for Lookup. but it didn't worked.

Used JNDITemplate Provided by Spring to lookup:

Used traditional approach like, creating ConnectionFactory object, then session, then Destination and then consumer and producer, but still the same issue persist


